# How would I take the derivative of a second derivative in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to reproduce a formula in a paper that I'm reading that does the following:
$$\int_0^{R} \frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2}\cdot \frac{dR_s}{dt} dR_s$$
According to the notes, the answer is:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2$$
How would I do this in Mathematica? I'm not entirely clear on multiplying differentials by differentials.

**Edit**:  The full text of the derivation in the paper is:
$$\frac{d^2R_s}{dt^2}=-\frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)^2}$$
*Multiplying both sides by $dR_s/t$ and integrating converts this "acceleration equation" to an "energy equation":*
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dR}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{GM_s}{R_s(t)}+U$$

Comment: your integration variable is $R'$ but your integrand has no $R'$ in it?

Comment: Thanks.  Does this edit look right?

Comment: No, since the command `D[1/2*f'[t]^2, t]` results in $f'(t) f''(t)$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica can do it if you mean the integral over t instead of Rs.  But it won't integrate definite integrals of derivatives any more.  It will do indefinite integrals.

```
Integrate[Rs'[t]*Rs''[t], t]
(*1/2 Rs'[t]^2*)
```

You can supply your own limits.  MMa stopped evaluating the definite integrals because it does not know the functions to be continuous.

Older versions such as M8 will do the definite integrals.

Comment: That is the concept I was missing.  The infinitesimals can be expressed as $R_s'[t]$ and multiplied just like any other variable.  That's the equivalent of $\frac{dR_s}{dt}$.  It makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You might hope to

```
Integrate[[Rs'[t] * (Rs'')[t], {t, 0, R}]
```

but unfortunately that won't work.  However, since you already have the answer, you can confirm by differentiation that

```
D[(1/2)*Rs'[t]^2, t]== Rs'[t]*Rs''[t]
```